# Python psycopg2 timeout

Tags: python, postgresql, connection, timeout, psycopg2

I have a huge problem:
There seems to be some hardware problems on the router of the server my python software runs on. The connection to the database only is successfull about every third time. So a psycopg2.connect() can take up to 5 minutes before I get an timeout exception.

```
2014-12-23 15:03:12,461 - ERROR - could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "172.20.19.1" and accepting
```

That's the code I'm using.

```
# Connection to the DB
try:
    db = psycopg2.connect(host=dhost, database=ddatabase,
                          user=duser, password=dpassword)
    cursor = db.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

except psycopg2.DatabaseError, err:
    print(str(err))
    logging.error(str(err))
    logging.info('program terminated')
    sys.exit(1)
```

I tried some timeout additions for the query, but that didn't helped, since the connection didn't got established at all.

Is there a way, I can stop the program immediately, when the connection couldn't be established?

Comment: perhaps blocked by some sort of application firewall?

Answer (score 82):

When using the keyword arguments syntax to the `connect` function it is possible to use any of the `libpd` supported connection parameters. Among those there is `connect_timeout` in seconds:

```
db = psycopg2.connect (
    host=dhost, database=ddatabase,
    user=duser, password=dpassword,
    connect_timeout=3
)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html

A connection time out raises an [`OperationalError`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.OperationalError) exception.

Comment: Going to comment first, though this might merit new ques: In my case I am getting the timeout, as well as this prompt: `Is the server running on host "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (xx.x.xxx.xxx) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`. The answer is indeed yes to those. In fact, I can make the connection in a node variation of this same tool, yet remain unable to connect via the `psycopg2` version I've written.

Comment: if you can do `psql "some connection string"`  then `psycopg2.connect(dsn="some connection string" )` should also work.

Comment: What's the difference between the timeout options in `PGOPTIONS` and the timeout options as part of libpq connect parameters?