# Why are the `keepalives` params in `psycopg2.connect(...)` required to run long running postgres queries in docker (ubuntu:18.04)?

Tags: postgresql, docker, psycopg2

We just transitioned to using Docker for development and are using the `ubuntu:18.04` image. We noticed that queries using `psycopg2` failed after a few minutes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56325038/604048) solved the problem using the following `keepalives` params:

```
self.db = pg.connect(
    dbname=config.db_name,
    user=config.db_user,
    password=config.db_password,
    host=config.db_host,
    port=config.db_port,
    keepalives=1,
    keepalives_idle=30,
    keepalives_interval=10,
    keepalives_count=5
)
```

This works for us as well, but **why** does this work? [The psycopg2 docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html) do not give insight into what the params do, however, [this third party](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tcp-keepalive-for-a-better-postgresql-experience/) documentation does, and [this postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-KEEPALIVES) documentation does.

The question is, what is different in the docker environment vs the host environment which makes these non-default settings required? They work in a standard Ubuntu 18.04 environment too, but not in docker. I am hoping we could reconfigure our docker image so that these non-standard parameters aren't necessary in the first place.

---

Postgres version: `PostgreSQL 13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit`

psycopg2 version: `2.8.5`

Host OS: Windows 10

Docker Image OS: Ubuntu 18:04

Comment: Docker should make no difference there. These settings only reduce the time it takes for the client to notice that the network connection or the server went away.

Comment: I understand. But they *do* make a difference. If I boot a VirtualBox up with Ubuntu 18.04 or if I run it on our native Ubuntu 18.04 servers, the connections stay alive, while if I run the same queries with the same connection parameters (not using keepalives) they fail on Docker running the standard Ubuntu 18.04 image on a windows host. This is also not just something weird with our setup, because others report this in the linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56325038/604048 I don't want these params set when we developed in docker, because they are not necessary at deploy.

Comment: The question you reference exhibits a network setup problem. You have to configure your network *not* to drop idle connections. Examine how the network setup is different in both cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using Dockers Overlay Network feature (or Ingress network for loadbalanced services), which is based on Linux IP Virtual Server (IPVS), a.k.a.Linux Virtual Server. This uses a default 900 second (15 minutes) timeout for idle TCP connections.

See: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31208

Default Linux TCP Keep-Alive settings only start sending packets much later (if enabled at all) and thus you are left with the options of:

- change the TCP Keep-Alive settings on the server or client
- change the Docker networking to use the host network directly
- change your software to avoid idle TCP connections, e.g. configure connection pools for databases to remove idle connections or check health more often
- change the Kernel IPVS defaults or TCP defaults